# filter column from a list on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to filter column D on sheet1 with information in column A on sheet "Lg" but nothing seems to happen.  I don't even get an error

```
Sub Filter()
'
' Filter Macro
'

'
    Columns("D:D").Select 'in Sheet 1
    Range("C1:C636").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("Lg").Columns("A:A"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: `D:D` is outside of `C1:C636`. Is this happening in the workbook containing this code? Does `MsgBox Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion` display the address of the correct range? Column A in worksheet `Lg` needs to have the same title (header) as column `D` in worksheet `Sheet1`. Please, add these and possibly other clarifying details [to your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71095048/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Advanced Filter Example (2 Worksheets)

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

- It is assumed that your data starts in cell `A1` and `CurrentRegion` works for referencing the complete range.
- The titles (headers) of the destination criteria column `D` on worksheet `Sheet1` and of the source criteria column `A` on worksheet `Lg` need to be the same.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestAdvancedFilter()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source (contains filter values)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Lg")
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A" & slRow)
    
    ' Destination (is being filtered)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If dws.FilterMode Then dws.ShowAllData
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    drg.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, srg

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, that totally works.  Thank you so much